# Database records aren't created when running cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara, factory-bot

I'm working on a rails project using, cucumber, capybara and factory girl, and recently updated from rails 3.0.3 to rails 3.0.5, deleted my Gemfile.lock, run the `bundle install` command, and it appears that cucumber or cucumber-rails got updated, because I had to run `rails g cucumber:install --capybara --rspec` again for and error that appeared.

**The thing is that know when I run cucumber all my features fails because doesn't find any records, not even the records I created (steps passes) in the Background section of the feature file**.

I tried the same gem version combination creating a new project and everything worked, but in my current project don't. What could be happening?

My gem versions are:

```
Using capybara (0.4.1) from https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git (at 0.4.1) 
Using cucumber (0.10.2) 
Using cucumber-rails (0.4.0) 
Using database_cleaner (0.6.6) 
Using factory_girl (1.3.3) 
Using factory_girl_rails (1.0.1) 
Using rails (3.0.5) 
Using rspec-core (2.5.1) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.5.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.5.0) 
Using rspec (2.5.0) 
Using rspec-rails (2.5.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the gem versions, I came back to cucumber-rails (0.3.2) and everything worked again